# Abort Axios request if function is called again

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, abort

I'm trying to find a way to cancel axios requests if another request happens before the first request is complete.

I want it to work as a function. I have made a function looking like this:

```
import axios from "axios";

async function paginatedActivities(pageNumber) {
  let controller = new AbortController();
  try {
    const fetchData = await axios.get(
      `${process.env.SERVERBASEURL}/activities/paginatedactivities`,
      {
        signal: controller.signal,
        params: { query: "query", pageNumber: pageNumber },
        withCredentials: true,
      }
    );

    return fetchData.data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    if (axios.isCancel(err)) console.log("request cancelled");
  }
}

export default paginatedActivities;
```

I can't figure out when to call "controller.abort()"..

The function could potentially be called again before it has done its job, and in such cases  i'd need it to abort.. any suggestions? (without using the "useEffect"-hook..)

Answer (score 2):

Make the controller a global variable so you can access it between calls of the function

```js
let controller;

async function paginatedActivities(pageNumber) {
   if (controller) controller.abort();
   controller = new AbortController();

   // Make the request

   controller = undefined; // Reset the variable so it's not aborted next time
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea! Currently I have the "paginatedActivities" function in another file and call it from a useEffect function. I can of course move it to the same file which would make above solution work. Out of curiosity, how would you do it if the function is in another file and called from a useEffect?

Comment: Store the controller in the parent file instead. See https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html